# Retrieve data from database and send it to ajax in laravel

Tags: mysql, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have laravel project and I want to retrieve data  from database and send it to ajax function 
this is the code of show ($ip) function

```
  public function show($id)
  {


 $result = DB::table('radcheck')get();
  return ( $result);
  //
   }
```

this is the code of ajax which is trying to retrieve data from that function but it can not

```
     $('.edit-user').on('click', function() {
       var id=$(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/users/' + id,
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
            success: function(hr_request) {


                alert(hr_request['username']);


            },
              error: function(hr_request) {

                  alert(hr_request['username']);




            }

        });
    });
```

there is no data can be retrieving, I think I must send data from controller to ajax using json data, but how can I send it as json data and how can I process this json data into ajax function

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#json-responses

Comment: first of all, what? you wan't to send DB data to AJAX? why? and u need a '->' before the get() function on your php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple .. you can do it like following :

```
public function show($id)
{
  $result = DB::table('radcheck')->get();
  return response()->json(['data' => $result]); // here 'data' is key to access $result in ajax response , it is optional.

}
```

In the ajax response you can console it using console.log(hr_request.data) and check your data result. Additionally , to access property you need to do **hr_request.data.property**

Hope it helps , Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your help but when I trying to alert the retrieved value using alert(data['username']) the error undefined is appear

Comment: @Muh , what are you getting in console.log(hr_request.data ,'output') ? inspect element of your browser and look for output. it will help me to solve your problem